# Why radio button click event behaves differently

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

[Example on JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yejinxin/RPSwD/).

The question is:

If the first click is on the radio button, it behaves normally; But if the first click is on span text (i.e. aaaa), it can not get the checked radio.

Please tell me why and how I can make it the same.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question!

Comment: well, the question should be as below: given that the first radio is checked, why clicking on span text "bbbb" behaves differently than clicking directly on the second radio input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code, which happens when the radio button is clicked:

```
var obj = $(e.target||e.srcElement).parent();
score = obj.find('input:checked').val();
```

Puts the parent in the `obj` variable, which is the containing DIV. This contains both of the radio buttons. It then finds the FIRST checked input element in that DIV, which is always the one with the 'first' value after it is checked.

You should just get the value of the item which was clicked:

```
score = $(e.target||e.srcElement).val();
```

This can be rewritten as

```
score = $(this).val();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RPSwD/10/

Comment: Your answer does work. But could please tell me why when we click on span text, "obj.find('input:checked')" can not find the correct checked radio, while when we click directly on radio, it does find the correct checked radio. Thanks you.

Comment: When you click on the span text, jQuery calls the .click function before it actually checks it. When you click directly on the radio button, the act of clicking on it makes it checked and then the .click function is fired. I'm not sure why this is, but this is how jQuery does it. When you click on the span, if you want to programmatically check the radio button before triggering the .click function you can use this code `.attr('checked', 'checked');` on the radio button.

Comment: @Timm Thanks, that helps me understand it better. So, calling .click function does not make radio button checked, and seems like this is designed, not a bug -- I'm still a little confused...

Answer (score 1):

See new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPSwD/12/).

The problem is this line:

```
score = obj.find('input:checked').val();
```

Change it to:

```
score = $(this).val();
```

The reason for this is that you're looking for the selected item in the div but on the first click, the item has yet to become selected. Given that the event is targeted at the radio button, you can assume that radio is the selected one.

Note also that you don't need to use `e.target||e.srcElement`. jQuery takes care of this for you. Use `$(this)` instead.

Additionally, you need to set a name on the radio buttons to stop both from becoming selected. Alternatively, if having both selected is desired behaviour, use check boxes instead.

Comment: you mean the radio item has not been selected when we firstly click on span text, right? But why it's different when it's firstly clicked directly on radio button?

Comment: @yejinxin Yes. The radio is not selected until after the event completes.

Comment: Could you please explain why this kind of difference happens. I'm new on JS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any of the `event` properties:

```
var score = $(this).val(); // in your '.x' click handler

$('.y').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev('.x').click();
});
```

Comment: @deifwud. You haven't explained why/how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

just wrap your radio button inside label tag like this

```
<label for="radio1">
   <input type=radio class="x" id="radio1" value="First"/>
   <span class="y">aaaa</span>
</label>
```

No need for extra jquery or javascript

check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RPSwD/11/)** here

Comment: Although this works, it is actually changing the semantics of the JS. Not a good solution.

Comment: @flem i thought of giving a better solution then what OP currently has

Comment: I don't agree that this is a better solution. The JS is broken and needs fixing. Your solution solves the problem but the broken JS remains.